# relative frame in pose tag is not working

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Defining the poses of models to other frames other than world frame is not working, neither raises any errors.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22341/relative-frame-in-pose-tag-is-not-working/) by [dogukan_altay](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9243/dogukan_altay/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo <= 10 doesn't support SDF  frames, see [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1982/parse-sdf-frame-elements-and-attributes).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1